# which gem doesn't show after gem install

Tags: rubygems

I typed

```
gem install some_gem
```

and I even saw the confirmation message

```
1 gem installed!
```

But when I type

```
which some_gem
```

I see a blank line.  What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

if a gem lacks an executable then `which some_gem` should return nothing.
try

```
gem query --name some_gem
```

or

```
gem list
```